# Position text in a CSS grid over an image

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS grid where I need to place some text over an image. Below is shown the code I use without text over the image.

```css
.sbp-item12 {
        grid-row: 6 / 7;
        grid-column: 9/13;
        height: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item12">
    <a href="#">
       <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
       <figure>
          <img src="https://placehold.it/380x250">
       </figure>
    </a>
 </div>
```

I tried to add the following to the code, but then the text is going in the bottom of my page, and is not staying inside the grid item. Does anybody have an idea how I can place text over the image in my grid item?

```css
.sbp-item12 {
    grid-row: 6 / 7;
    grid-column: 9/13;
    height: 250px;
}

.bottom-left {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item12">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="text-bottm-left">
            <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
        </div>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/380x250">
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @satyam-pathak This here is about CSS grid. Far from being a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set parent `position:relative` and set the `position:absolute` for the `div` which you want to place at `bottom-left`.
Note: Your `Html` and `css` classes doesn't match. You need to correct them. Below is the working snippet

```css
.sbp-item12 {
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  grid-column: 9/13;
  height: 250px;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative
}

.bottom-left h3{
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin:0
}
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item12">
  <a href="#">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/380x250">
      <div class="bottom-left">
        <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is looking like something, thank you. Then I can set the placement of the text with `top, right, bottom, right` - is that coorect?

Comment: Yeah, You can place the text as per your requirement. Please accept the answer if it helped you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.sbp-item12 {
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  grid-column: 9/13;
  height: 250px;
}

div.img-post {
  position: relative;
}

h3.img-title { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left:175px; 
}

img.img-body { 
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item12 img-post">
    <a href="#">
       <h3 class="img-title">Here is a headline</h3>
       <figure>
          <img class="img-body" src="https://placehold.it/380x250">
       </figure>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortuanlly it is not working. If I use the img class all my other images are affected. I tried to give the image a seperate class to avoid that, but the text is still not inside the image :-(

Comment: I've updated the code and added few classes, so that this does not affect other images in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bottom-left {
  /* Insert your text styling here*/
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sbp-item12 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  grid-column: 9/13;
  height: 250px;
}

.sbp-item12 .bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* If text should be centered: */
  /* text-align: center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item12">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="bottom-left">
      <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
    </div>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/380x250" alt="Here is a headline" />
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just mistake in your code change this `class="text-bottm-left"` and add it `class="bottom-left"` I hope it will be work.

```
<div class="sbp-item12">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="bottom-left">
            <h3>Here is a headline</h3>
        </div>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/380x250">
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parent div in relative position using `position: relative` and then after setting the text into absolute position using `position: absolute`.

You use other CSS property like left, right, top, bottom to set the test wherever you want.